# Calculating how long it will take to pay off a loan

Tags: python

I'm stuck in my exercise about how long it will take to pay off a loan. I'm trying to do a loop calculating the interest and new balance after each monthly payment. Here what's I have so far:

```
def conta ():
  total = float(input('How much do you want to borrow?'))
  qtoPg = float(input('What is the monthly payment amount?'))
  annualInterest = float(input('What is the annual interest rate expressed as a percent?'))
  rateMonth = (annualInterest*0.01)/12
  tjm = total*rateMonth
  nbalance = total+tjm-qtoPg
  while nbalance <= qtoPg:
    tjm = nbalance*rateMonth
  print (nbalance)
```

Comment: Did you [debug](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should use EMI concept. Add to total amount the monthly interest and subtract the EMI amount paid per month. When the balance amount is less than or equal to zero then break the loop.

The below modified function will print the number of EMI's to be paid.

```
def conta ():
  
  total = float(input('How much do you want to borrow? '))
  qtoPg = float(input('What is the monthly payment amount? '))
  annualInterest = float(input('What is the annual interest rate expressed as a percent? '))
  
  rateMonth = (annualInterest*0.01)/12
  
  nbalance = total
  emis = 0
  
  while nbalance > 0:
    emis += 1
    nbalance = nbalance + (rateMonth*nbalance)
    
    nbal = qtoPg
    if nbalance < qtoPg:
      nbal = nbalance
    
    nbalance -= qtoPg

    if nbalance <= 0:
      print(nbal)
    
  print (emis)
```

Comment: Tks for your help! How can I make the code show the amount of the final payment?

Comment: Did you mean total amount paid? or the last EMI amount?

Comment: The amount of the last payment if is less than the monthly payment

Comment: I marked it as right but I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet, my apologies! Thank you so much

Comment: code updated, check now

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your quick responses, I hope to repay the favor one day!

Answer (score 2):

I don’t see how that is even supposed to work.

You have a loop where the exit condition compares `nbalance` and `qtoPg` but inside the loop, those values are not changed.

Also, your basic math is wrong.  Each month, the balance goes down by the payment-amount, but it goes up by the interest due, which is based on the balance, not the original principal.